# Grouping by preserving hours in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dateframe. I would like to groupby mean every hour but still preserv the hours datetime info.

```
    date                    A      I   r         z
0 2017-08-01 00:00:00       3      56  4         6.   
1 2017-08-01 00:00:01       3      57  1         6   
2 2017-08-01 00:00:03       3      58  9         6   
3 2017-08-01 00:00:05       3      52  10        2.  
4 2017-08-01 00:00:06       3      50  1         1  

df.groupby(df['date'].dt.hour).mean()

date         A      I   r         z
    0        3      56  4         6.   
    1        3      57  1         6   
    2        3      58  9         6   
    3        3      52  10        2.  
    4        3      50  1         1
```

I would like to have as an index the same date before such as `2017-08-01 00:00:00` datetime64[ns]

How can I achieve this output in Python?

Output desired:

```
date                        A      I   r         z
0 2017-08-01 00:00:00       3      56  4         6.   
1 2017-08-01 01:00:00       3      57  1         6   
2 2017-08-01 02:00:00       3      58  9         6   
3 2017-08-01 03:00:00       3      52  10        2.  
4 2017-08-01 04:00:00       3      50  1         1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `resample`

```
df.set_index('date').resample('H').mean()
Out[179]: 
                       A      I    r    z
date                                     
2017-08-01 00:00:00  3.0  55.75  6.0  5.0
2017-08-01 01:00:00  NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-08-01 02:00:00  NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-08-01 03:00:00  3.0  50.00  1.0  1.0
```

Data input

```
                 date  A   I   r    z
0 2017-08-01 00:00:00  3  56   4  6.0
1 2017-08-01 00:00:01  3  57   1  6.0
2 2017-08-01 00:00:03  3  58   9  6.0
3 2017-08-01 00:00:05  3  52  10  2.0
4 2017-08-01 03:00:06  3  50   1  1.0# different hour here
```

Comment: This won't work the same way OP intends. I think they want to group by the hour, regardless of the day, I think.

Comment: @coldspeed yep , he need to clarify his question :-)

Comment: I understand the issue here because it can only be used in a day interval not with differing from several days right?

Comment: @may yes , multiple date groupby hour , it will not show the date,cause the date is different

Comment: @Wen it will resample all days right by hours and keep the index? this is what I see here

Comment: @may yes, it will